# HANA: Unknown Characters in Database column of datatype BLOB

Tags: sql, hana, character-set

I need help on how to resolve characters of unknown type from a database field into a readable format, because I need to overwrite this value on database level with another valid value (in the exact format the application stores it in) to automate system copy acitvities.

I have a proprietary application that also allows users to configure it in via the frontend. This configuration data gets stored in a table and the values of a configuration property are stored in a column of type "BLOB". For the here desired value, I provide a valid URL in the application frontend (like http://myserver:8080). However, what gets stored in the database is not readable (some square characters). I tried all sorts of conversion functions of HANA (HEX, binary), simple, and in a cascaded way (e.g. first to binary, then to varchar) to make it readable. Also, I tried it the other way around and make the value that I want to insert appear in the correct format (conversion to BLOL over hex or binary) but this does not work either. I copied the value to clipboard and compared it to all sorts of character set tables (although I am not sure if this can work at all).

My conversion tries look somewhat like this:

`SELECT TO_ALPHANUM('') FROM DUMMY;`

while the brackets would contain the characters in question. I cant even print them here.

How can one approach this and maybe find out the character set that is used by this application? I would be grateful for some more ideas.

Comment: BLOBs are for binary data, use CLOB or NCLOB data type for character data.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your BLOB column is a series of bytes. As you mentioned, these bytes have been written by an application that uses an unknown character set.

In order to interpret those bytes correctly, you need to know the character set as this is literally the mapping of bytes to characters or character identifiers (e.g. code points in UTF).

Now, HANA doesn't come with a whole lot of options to work on LOB data in the first place and for C(haracter)LOB data most manipulations implicitly perform a conversion to a string data type.

So, what I would recommend is to write a custom application that is able to read out the BLOB bytes and perform the conversion in that custom app. Once successfully converted into a string you can store the data in a new NVCLOB field that keeps it in UTF-8 encoding.

You will have to know the character set in the first place, though. No way around that.

Comment: I suspected this would be the only way. But it was worth a try. Thank you Lars and by the way thanks for all the HANA content over the years. Really helpful stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback @Laghorn! Appreciate that - it's immensely motivating to get some positive response on the content that I put into the "void" of the internet. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on Oracle. You can convert BLOB to CLOB as described here.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_clob_script.htm

In case of your example try this query:

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(<your_blob_value)) from dual;
```

Obviously this only works for values below 32767 characters.

Comment: Sorry, I am on HANA. The column type is blob but the thing about my problem is (at least I think), the application involved uses a weird character set and therfore I can not read the contents. Any given string I convert to BLOB, CLOB and NCLOB ist still readable. So it cant be about the datatype.